# Не получается подключить jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не понимаю в чём проблема, код страницы выдаёт ошибку "uncaught referenceerror: jQuery is not defined at"

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="jQuery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Попробуйте `./jQuery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js`, а ещё лучше `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 
</head>
<body>
    

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
       </script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Roman, а почему он с серверов берёт файл, а с пк моего нет, я делал всё по уроку?

Comment: надо смотреть структуру проекта, может не правильно прописываете путь к файлу или или скрипт неправильный, может быть много причин.